# Display a toast message when exiting while also turning off Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am wanting to display a toast message when I exit the app just like the title says.  I am unable to use the following because of the restraints of the OnClickListener.

```
btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // close the application and turn off bluetooth
            btAdapter.disable();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is turned off.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

    });
```

I want to be able to click the button and exit the program while turning off Bluetooth and displaying a toast saying the Bluetooth is turned off

Answer (score 3):

In the [Toast.makeTest()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29), the first parameter is the context. In your code you are passing `this`, which in your case is the `onClickListener`. You are supposed to pass the `context` there, which could be something like `YourActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

Use your **ActivityName.this** instead of **this** in Toast.